# Why does a redraw loop alias my HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been having difficulty with producing crisp shapes on my canvas, I've been taking out code to try and debug it and it seems one of the causes is the fact that's being redrawn. Below is the code without a loop:

```js
var context = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.width, context.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 4;
  context.strokeStyle = 'darkred';
  context.stroke();
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=200></canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the same again with the loop:

```js
var context = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.width, context.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 4;
  context.strokeStyle = 'darkred';
  context.stroke();
}

function init() {
  if (typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
  var game_loop = setInterval(draw, 30);
}
init();
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=200></canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For those who do not see what I do in Chrome, here's an image:
[image: Circle with anti-aliasing, and circle without]

It would seem that even putting the line `requestAnimationFrame(draw);` in the first example causes the same issue.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot access `context.width` and `context.height`. Therefore this will cause the `clearRect` method to fail and have the circles being drawn over another.
Use `canvas.width`and `canvas.height`.

```js
var canvas = $('canvas')[0]
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var game_loop

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 4;
  context.strokeStyle = 'darkred';
  context.stroke();
}

function init() {
  if (typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
  game_loop = setInterval(requestAnimationFrame.bind(null, draw), 30) // use requestAnimationFrame but limit to 30ms interval - from @JoshuaK
}
init();
```

```html
<canvas width=200 height=200></canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also you used both, an interval and the `requestAnimationFrame`. Which will cause massive lags. Use intervals for anmation only when you have no other option. You could also use this polyfill:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = function(){
    return (
        window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
        function(func){
            window.setTimeout(func, 30);
        }
    );
}()
```

Comment: The answer is ofcourse correct, but why do you change his 30ms setting? There is no need for changing that...

Comment: @JoshuaK if you look closely, he already used `requestAnimationFrame` inside the loop.

Comment: Sure. I saw that. But he want's to update every 30ms. Why do you changed that? You could have left this preset inside your example. (I pretty sure it doesn't matter for the questioner ;) Just wonderd)

Comment: @JoshuaK `requestAnimationFrame` is the proper way to do it. Do me a favor and run his second snippet and wait 10-20s. Your browser will start to lag. But yes, ofcourse... It doesnt really matter.

Comment: My browser doesn't lag after 3 minutes (his snippet is running all the time). Sure `requestAnimationFrame` IS the right and best choice. `requestAnimationFrame` needn't to be called recursively till the end. You could remove it from the draw method and write: `setTimeout(requestAnimationFrame.bind(null, draw), 30)`. This is ok if draw needs less than 30ms. Or you could use delta of the given argument and messure the time between the calls from requestAnimationFrame to keep the 30ms delay from his code in your code.

Comment: @JoshuaK neat, I've put that in.

Comment: @JoshuaK Your setTimeout advice is terrible. Don't mix setTimeout with rAF. If you need to set a slower fps rate, indeed, do it in the rAF callback, by checking the timestamp argument. setTimeout is not reliable and you may well end up stacking twice or thrice rAF callbacks in the same frame or, more likely in this case, miss frames. And Manuel Otto, your implementation of this terrible advice doesn't loop...

Comment: Thankyou @ManuelOtto for the `requestAnimationFrame` polyfill information! The 30ms I added was just a random number, and I added the `requestAnimationFrame` last minute anyway.

Comment: @kaiido you can do that if you Know what you're doing. There is no problem with that if you keep in mind that draw has to be faster than 30ms. The stacking can also be watched inside draw if needed.

Comment: @JoshuaK and how will you know the drawing would have taken more than 30ms? Stacked rAF callbacks share the same timestamp. And setting a way access the setTimeout loop from inside the callback is just over-complication. Just stick with *don not mix looped timeouts with rAF and you'll be fine.

Comment: @kaiido let's say I have to update my view every 10 seconds... Why should I call requestAnimationFrame and my function every few ms? That's terrible. It's named requestAnimationFrame for a reason. It is meant to be called if there is something to update. If not: don't call it.

Comment: @JoshuaK but for a case like a frame every 10s why would you use rAF anyway? Sure there are usage for setTimeout and setInterval, I just say they shouldn't be mixed up with rAF.

Answer (score 1):

[`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) (the type of `context`) has no `width` and `height` attribute, but it keeps a reference to the [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/canvas) it belongs to.

And of course that has `width`/`height`, so the minimal change in your code could be:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
```

Comment: Seems strange that works: so it's basically `canvas.context.canvas`?

Comment: @jaunt extended the answer a little now (originally I was typing on mobile in the night)

Answer (score 1):

If you changed the transformation matrix (for example using scale, rotation, or translation), context.clearRect (0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height) will probably not remove the entire visible part Canvas

The solution? Reset the transformation matrix before clearing the canvas:

```
// Store the current transformation matrix
context.save();

// Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Restore the transform
context.restore();
```